# EOS 700D freezes in live view / video mode, on JPEG conversion, or fast RAW shoots

Tags: canon, live-view, canon-700d, hangs

*see update below.*

all out of a sudden my EOS 700D tends to freeze when in live view or video recording mode. Sometimes the live view shows a still image that's several seconds old and doesn't refresh, sometimes there are pixel fault patterns in that still image. And sometimes the display shows just some colorful gibberish. Taking photos still works correctly, both in live view or non-live-view modes, but after 30 secs - 1 minute in live view mopde the camera locks up completely (only removing the battery works). Taking videos does not work, the video duration stays at 0:00.

Strangely, displaying photos and all menus work correctly, so it's certainly not a display fault. I've just updated the firmware to the most recent version (1.1.4 -> 1.1.5) and tried it with a different lens - to no avail. Both lenses and the SD card work in my EOS 600D.

Unfortunately, my Camera is 8 days out of warranty, so this makes me feel like this error was scheduled (although it's probably just bad luck).

Any ideas what could cause this error, and maybe how to diagnose / fix this? See some pictures attached.

Thanks in advance, Lukas

**UPDATE:** Several months have passed, since the original errors occured, so I want to give an update on how the issue evolved afterwards, in the hope that it may help someone.

The camera worked flawlessly, at least for RAW + JPEG shoots w/o liveview. At some point, even the live view and video modes worked again, so I already was relieved and thought, the issue was solved.

But then, unfortunately, two weeks ago the issues got worse again: all out of a sudden, the camera even locked up at regular RAW + JPEG shoots through the viewfinder. Video and live view mode stopped working as well. A firmware reinstall or formatting / switching the SD-card had no effect. I figured out that RAW-only mode works as expected, even at fast shoots, while every mode involving JPEG would cause the camera to lock.

For another week, the camera worked fine in RAW-only mode, until now, where even in RAW-only mode fast shoots cause the camera to lock up. This makes the camera pretty unusable now, which is sad, since the photos are still fine and the camera is not very old. I'll have to take a repair into consideration, and expect a high cost.

**UPDATE 2:** I am still using the camera without having done any repairs. It works reliably in RAW mode, JPEG mode sometimes works, even for weeks, and then doesn't work again for weeks. Using live view or video mode seems to kill the camera within minutes, causing everything except RAW not working again for weeks. But I can refrain from using JPEG and stay with RAW, instead of paying the repair fees.

[image: Display shows colorful gib]
Display shows colorful gibberish

[image: Display shows old still image with pixel errors]
Display shows old still image with pixel errors

[image: Camera locked up completely (no menus / buttons / power switch work)]
Camera locked up completely (no menus / buttons / power switch work)

Comment: Broken electronics, ask a camera repair shop for a quote

Comment: Was the end result a new circuit board in this case also. My EOS700D developed exactly the same problem yesterday? From the sound of it I need to get it to a Canon repairer and expect a hefty bill!

Comment: I haven’t done any repair yet. My camera was not in use a few weeks after that issue appeared. After that, it occurred to me that video mode and live view mode now work again with minor issues. The screen is still flickering or showing pixel faults when in live view mode, but it doesn’t hang or fail completely. I’ve done some video recording since then (although not very long, only a few minutes each time) but that worked. Image preview also shows some flickering, but works in general. If it stays that way, I’ll avoid the high cost of a repair.

Comment: I guess, the issue occurs if high bandwidth needs to be displayed on the screen. Since menus don’t show the issues, only when displaying image data, e.g. complex data, which means a lot of bandwidth. So probably some kind of display controller or display cable fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently had the same problem (also 700D, bought in 2014). Everytime I switched to the Live View my camera froze (either to a freeze frame or the pixels you have) and I could only mend the problem by taking the battery out.

I sent the camera to a Canon repair partner and their inspection came to the conclusion that the PCB = printed circuit board (I hope that is the correct translation, in German it's called "Platine") had to be replaced, which is apparently the most expensive part of the camera body. All in all, I had to pay 260€ for the replacement, works and transport. Obviously, those prices can vary a lot and depend on your repair shop but it looks like you have the same problem and maybe that helps as an orientation for you.

Sorry not to have better news, I hope you can sort it out the cheapest and most efficient way possible :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I feared this outcome, but expected it. I'm also from Germany, what store did you send your camera to?

Comment: @LukeLR Es gibt auf der Seite von Canon eine Liste von deren Reparaturstellen (http://www.canon.de/support/consumer_products/repair.aspx). Für die Eos Kamera gibt es aber nur eine in Willich, aber vielleicht hast du Glück und kannst einfach vorbei gehen^^ Amazon (weil ich die Kamera dort gekauft habe) hat mich an die Firma Rüdiger März (Filiale Hamburg) weitergeleitet (für mich die nächste). Die haben mir auch eine Analyse und Kostenvoranschlag angefertigt, (sollte man die Reparatur dann nicht in Anspruch nehmen, kostet das allerdings 34€+Versand). Aber das machen wohl alle Service Stellen so

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort! Zufälligerweise wohne ich ganz in der Nähe von Willich, ich werde mich also mal informieren und dann da mal vorbeifahren :) Wenn sich etwas ergeben hat, werde ich nochmal berichten. Vielen Dank für den Tipp! -- Thanks for your reply! By Chance, I'm living only 20 Minutes from Willich, so I'll probably drop my camera off at that repair shop. I'll update if something changes :)